# Scipy minimize function on matrix x0

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

Scipy optimize.minimize seems to accept only single-dimension x0. I have a problem where my x0 are shape(n, m). Constraints exist such that each row of x0 should match a certain value.

I could simply iterate through each row and perform the optimization on that; however, I'm hoping to add constraints to the columns at some point.

Is there a known way of handling this? I can't find much discussion of it. I've tried various versions of broadcasting, flattening, etc., but haven't had much luck in creating a reasonable structure.

EDIT: I've added a minimal code example. The constraint condition returns proper zeros when tested with test_x.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize

def cost(x, p):
    x.reshape(3, 4)
    p.reshape(3, 4)
    return (x * p).sum()

def demand_constraint(x, d):
    x = x.reshape(3, 4)
    b = x.sum(axis=0) - d
    return np.broadcast_to(b, (3, 4)).flatten()

demand = np.array([10, 14, 8, 26])
prices = np.array([[4, 4, 5, 5], [2, 8, 6, 2], [3, 2, 9, 8]])
x0 = np.zeros_like(prices).flatten()
p0 = prices.flatten()

test_x = np.array([[4, 14, 8, 26], [5, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]])


cost(x0, p0)

cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': demand_constraint, 'args': (demand,)})

output = scipy.optimize.minimize(cost, x0, args=p0, constraints=cons)
```

Comment: Just reshape the flat 1d x-vec to whatever you need within your constraint (first line preprocessing)? API-wise, you will have to follow the 1d-restriction.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, sascha. The output of the constraint then has to be sent back to the same size as x, correct? I tried that with broadcasting. If that's right, I'll keep plugging away. :-)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may encounter this in a search, the way to handle it is to add a constraint for every individual row. So the demand_constraint above will take a row_index field and a single value will be returned.

This single value can then be incorporated into a constraint that is added. You continue to add constraints (each it's own dictionary) for the shape. My mistake was to assume that the constraint could apply to all of the x. It's better suited to apply to a single x.